# Why are the character fields of a transparent table in SAP 3 times bigger on the database level (DB2)?

Tags: unicode, db2, sap-data-dictionary

I work with an SAP system with an IBM DB2 database attached to it. I created a transparent table in SAP system and then I checked how it looked like on the database level. It turned out that the character fields (`CHAR`, `DATS`, `CUKY`, `NUMC`) are three times bigger than their length specified in `SE11`. For example `CLIENT` field of type `MANDT` has the type `VARCHAR(9)`.

I could understand multiplication of the length by 2 because of the fact that SAP is a Unicode system. But the multiplication by 3? Is anybody able to explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect does not depend on the DBMS used (I'm seeing the same effect on Oracle-based systems). It really is a unicode/NUC issue: On a NUC system, the client field is a `VARCHAR2(3)`, on a unicode system of otherwise identical software components, it's a `VARCHAR2(9)`. I can only guess that this is due to the usage of some [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) variant.

Comment: UTF-8 can use up to 4 bytes per glyph, but it seems that it's not very common to encounter 4-byte characters so using 3x is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: I have also found a very interesting article on this topic [Forms of Unicode](http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/forms_of_unicode/)